# How to generate Key Pairs with eosjs

Tags: eosjs, keys

How to generate eos Key Pairs with eosjs? I have installed EOSIO for development of my Dapp and can't figure out how to create Key Pairs with eosjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc) or [eosjs-keygen](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-keygen) to generate key pairs.

Comment: how is it done with eosjs v21?